# Insert and Save to DB in Catch Statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to save data to database in catch statement exception handling ??

I want to write log of the error record to another table to prevent duplication of the primary key

```
foreach(var i in impCSV)
{
    try
    {
        var addrDet = new AddrDetail()
        {
            Road = i.w_addr1,
            Road2 = i.w_addr2,
            Road3 = i.w_addr3,
            City = i.w_city,
            Zipcode = i.w_zip
        };

        var invoice = new Invoice()
        {
            InvoiceNo = i.rec_no
        };

        var image = new Models.Image()
        {
            Image1 = null
        };

        var detail = new DetailPengiriman()
        {
            TrDate = null,
            InsertDate = DateTime.Parse(i.doc_dt)
        };

        var cust = db.Customers.Find(i.cust_id);                  
        if (cust !=null)
        {
            cust.CustID = i.cust_id;
            cust.Phone = i.w_phone1;
            cust.CustComp = i.company;
            cust.Fullname = i.fullname;

            db.Entry(cust).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            cust = new Customer()
            {
                CustID = i.cust_id,
                Phone = i.w_phone1,
                CustComp = i.company,
                Fullname = i.fullname
            };

            db.Customers.Add(cust);
        }
        invoice.CustID = cust.CustID;

        db.AddrDetails.Add(addrDet);
        invoice.AddrDetID = addrDet.AddrDetID;      

        db.Images.Add(image);
        invoice.ImageID = image.ImageID;

        db.Invoices.Add(invoice);
        stat.InvoiceNo = invoice.InvoiceNo;
        detail.InvoiceNo = invoice.InvoiceNo;

        detail.CompID = compID;
        db.DetailPengirimen.Add(detail);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var logEr = new LogErrorImport()
        {
            custid = i.cust_id,
            fullname = i.fullname,
            company = i.company,
            re = i.rec_no,
            doc = i.doc_dt,
            addr1 = i.w_addr1,
            addr2 = i.w_addr2,
            addr3 = i.w_addr3,
            city = i.w_city,
            zip = i.w_zip,
            phone = i.w_phone1
        };
        db.LogErrorImports.Add(logEr);
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The save changes command in catch statement also save all the record in try statement so i get error because of duplicate primary key

All I want is only save the data to LogError table and continue the foreach process

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: No matter what the question is, trying to save data in a catch statement is a very, very bad idea, especially if it's a generic `catch`. You have no idea what went wrong, why are you trying to save again? How do you know that saving was at fault and why do you think that blindly performing the same action would have different results?

Comment: how to save changes in the catch statement there, cause when i saveChanges it gets the error of primary key duplication, but that error is what i want to catch and log it

Comment: Furthermore, calling `SaveChanges` inside a loop is extremely wasteful. You execute a separate command for each iteration when you could save everything with a single call outside the loop

Comment: i just want to know which record return error, so i make log table there

Comment: @newbs simple  - don't. Don't do that, don't save in the loop. The exception will tell you what went wrong. *DON'T* try to log using the *SAME* connection that faulted either

Comment: BTW - if the first `SaveChanges` failes, the second will try to execute the **SAME** statements again. The changes weren't discarded by the exception. Just **DON'T** use the same context for logging

Comment: so how to insert the error record to the logError table ?

Comment: Ignoring the pros and cons of writing to to DB in a catch (there are many cons). No one can answer this. Your getting an error because your trying to insert a duplicate primary key. **We don't know what your primary keys are or what values your inserting**.

Comment: inside the try statement there is an error of primary key duplication, so i want to catch that error and insert to log table which primary key is duplicated

Comment: @newbs No. Inside the catch statement you have all the previous changes, plus your log entry. You are trying to save the same data twice

Comment: yeah i already got the answer by making a new connection for saving to the log, but i got another principal error for the next record i inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify the Primary Key on your `LogErrorImport` table. Make sure it is an identity column which is set to auto increment. Do not set this primary key anywhere in your code. If these checks are alright, you shouldn't be getting duplicate Primary Key error.

**Update:**
You will need to define different sets of 'db' context in `try` and `catch` block with `using` statement so that they do not conflict with each other. You might do something like:

```
try
{
   using (var _context = new DBContext())
   {
      //Normal save logic here
     _context.Save();
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   using (var _context = new DBContext())
   {
      //Log error here
     _context.Save();
   }
}
```

Comment: like @Panagiotis said, if the first SaveChanges failes, the second will try to execute the SAME statements again. The changes weren't discarded by the exception.

Comment: @newbs Please check if updated answer works for you.

Comment: wow it works thx haha, but there is another problem after catch the process get loop start again because of the foreach, and then i get principal error.... If there is an error and enter catch i always get principal error for the next record, but if there wasnt any error from the first record and doesnt enter catch i didnt get principal error for the next record

Comment: @newbs don't reuse context, especially failed one. At the start of try block create new context, at the end dispose, just like this answer shows.

Comment: yes i already did it and it works haha, but i got another principal error for the next record i inserted

Comment: So... What happens to your code if the reason it failed was that it couldn't connect to the database at all? The code in your catch will fail too because it is trying to connect to the same database.

Comment: You should probably look at some of the many fine logging frameworks out there already and use one of them instead.